# Bending / simple model with material

Tags: modeling, materials

I am trying to do a relatively simple thing but can't make it, so if anyone is willing to help, here is the problem. Have in mind that I am very new to Blender (5th day:)
[image]
It's a foldable paper gift box model that consists of two parts (attch img). You arrange them in cross flat on the surface and flip all four ends locking them together pulling the ends of one through the slots in the other.

I would like to bend the two parts and apply material that I can change when I multiply the model. But, it is falling appart - the outline that is imported from ai has some holes where material is not showing, I can't manipulate the parts in such a way to get the shape that I need and so on.

Can anyone help?

[image]
enter image description here

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you just want to recreate the same in 4th image?

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking. Are trying to animate the folding process? Model the folded result? Deal with the horizontal gaps in the textured mesh? At this point I would recommend uploading your current .blend (use File->External Data->Pack All into .blend first) https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I am trying to model the gift box in the 4th photo and apply material to it. Problems I have - I can't fold the that one piece in this way / if I brake it in pieces, I lose some surfaceses and material on it.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5946" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5946/)